# ResKit 0.20.0 "Expected a type" error

Tags: objective-c, restkit, restkit-0.20

Why does the following code produce an `Expected a type` error?

```
@interface UUUExampleAPI ()
- (void)fireErrorBlock:(RKRequestDidFailLoadWithErrorBlock)failBlock onErrorInResponse:(RKResponse *)response;
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `RKRequestDidFailLoadWithErrorBlock` and `RKResponse` are available in RestKit 0.10.3 but not 0.20.0.